# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' (load scss file)

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, loader

I got some webpack error says

> ERROR in ./src/js/containers/App.js
> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /Users/chunza2542/Desktop/odnpoll/src/js/containers
> @ ./src/js/containers/App.js 13:11-32

I try to install `resolve-url-loader` NPM package. And I config `webpack.config.js` but I got the same error again.

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./src/js/main.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            query: {
              sourcemap: true,
              module: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            query: {
              outputStyle: 'expanded',
              sourcemap: true
            }
          },
          'resolve-url'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  devServer:{
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Thank for help.

## EDIT

You can see my code & File Directory in this link
https://s24.postimg.org/dbk1txd05/Screen_Shot_2016_12_07_at_7_39_05_PM.png

Comment: it seems you are importing/requiring a file that does not exists

Comment: @nikhilmehta This is my code & File directory https://s24.postimg.org/dbk1txd05/Screen_Shot_2016_12_07_at_7_39_05_PM.png

Comment: try commenting the line import design from './App.scss'